# Dropdown List Not Populating Correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `Edit Account` page whereby people can update information via the State, District and Company dropdown lists which are *pre-populated* with data.  The problem I am encountering is when a person chooses a different State, the districts for the new chosen State are not populating in the District dropdown list; it actually keeps the districts of the previous State.  How do I make the districts for the new chosen State show up in the District dropdown list?  Any help is much appreciated.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Panel ID="editAcctPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="submitButton" ValidationGroup="EditAccount">

<asp:Label ID="stateLbl" runat="server" Text="State:" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="stateDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="StateName" DataValueField="StateID" OnDataBound="stateDDL_DataBound" Width="205px">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM State"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />

<asp:Label ID="DistLbl" runat="server" Text="District:" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="districtDDL" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="DistrictName" DataValueField="DistrictID" OnDataBound="districtDDL_DataBound" Width="65%">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT DistrictID, DistrictName FROM District ORDER BY DistrictName">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />

<asp:Label ID="CompanyLbl" runat="server" Text="Company:" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="companyDDL" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="CompanyName" DataValueField="CompanyID" OnDataBound="companyDDL_DataBound" Width="65%">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT CompanyID, CompanyName FROM Company ORDER BY CompanyName">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="submitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submitButton_Click" ValidationGroup="EditAccount" />

</asp:Panel>
```

**C#**

```
protected void stateDDL_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //stateDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Select a State -", "NA"));
    //stateDDL.SelectedValue = "AL";
}

protected void districtDDL_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //districtDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Select a District -", "00"));
}

protected void companyDDL_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //companyDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Select a Company -", "00"));
}
….
….
SqlDataReader reader = GetInfo.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            stateDDL.SelectedValue = reader["StateIDNum"].ToString();
            if (reader["DistrictGroupIDNum"].Equals(1))
            {
                districtDDL.SelectedValue = reader["DistrictID"].ToString();
                companyDDL.SelectedValue = reader["CompanyIDNum"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                companyfNameTxtbox.Text = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                companylNameTxtBox.Text = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                companyemailTxtBox.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
            }

        }
        reader.Close();

    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is State filter in District Dropdown datasource?

Comment: this sounds like a DataSource Issue meaning when you make a change in the DDL, are you checking to make sure that State is being Filtered.. look at your Initial Sql Query.. the first time it loads.. it works.. the next time you make a change it works based on your `Select * From` you need to have a where clause.. and I would suggest using a different approach to bind / load the DDL for the States..you need to add break points and step through the code as well

Comment: What you want are **cascading drop down lists**.  There are plenty of examples on the web.

Comment: Looks like you are missing an `OnIndexChange` event for your state dropdown that will reload your District dropdown

Comment: Do you have code in `Page_Load` that populates your `DropDownList` with it's initial data? Then add a `if(IsPostBack)`-check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of several folks, I managed to make the District dropdown list to work.

**ASPX**
Added OnSelectedIndexChanged

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="stateDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="StateName" DataValueField="StateID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="stateDDL_OnSelectedIndexChanged" 
                Width="205px">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM State"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**C#**
SqlDataSource3 for District

```
protected void stateDDL_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters.Clear();
    SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters.Add("@StateIDNum", "StateIDNum");
    SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters["@StateIDNum"].DefaultValue = stateDDL.SelectedValue;
    districtDDL.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource3";
    districtDDL.DataBind();
}
```